# Playing sound with CrossSimpleAudioPlayer - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Recently I've been trying to use **CrossSimpleAudioPlayer** in Xamarin Forms to play **.mp3** file, but I'm receiving this message

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I changed the property Build Action to **Embedded Resource**, but my error persist, is something i'm missing here?

This is my reference https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/?utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog&utm_source=linkedin&utm_content=simpleaudioplayer-nuget and this is my code:

```js
public void Play() {
  var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  Stream audioStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("softAlarm." + "softAlarm.mp3");
  var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
  audio.Load(audioStream);

  audio.Play();
}
```

Comment: Where is your `softAlarm.mp3` file located? You need to put in the full path concatenated with dots, prefixed by your project name. So if you file is in a project called SoftAlarm under the resources folder, you should state: `GetManifestResourceStream("SoftAlarm.Resources.softAlarm.mp3")`

Comment: Then you probably should just do this: `GetManifestResourceStream("softAlarm.mp3")` as the OS will find it for you. But not entirely sure on this one. The link you're referring to also places the audio file in the shared library. That way you don't need any duplicate files as well :)

Comment: so i tried like ... GetManifestResourceStream("MyProcet.softAlarm.mp" )and just GetManifestResourceStream("softAlarm.mp3"), error perssist

Comment: And you did add the sound file to your shared project with the right build action while trying the first option?

Comment: I've created a sample project for you here: https://github.com/jfversluis/CrossSimpleAudioPlayerSample

Comment: @GeraldVersluis sir add your answer and I give it to you as best, really thank for your time.

Comment: Done, thank you! And no problem at all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where is your `softAlarm.mp3` file located? You need to put in the full path concatenated with dots, prefixed by your project name.

So, if your file is in a project called *SoftAlarm* under the *Resources* folder, you should state: `GetManifestResourceStream("SoftAlarm.Resources.softAlarm.mp3");`

The sound file should be in your shared project and have the build action **Embedded Resource**.

I have created a working sample project for you here: https://github.com/jfversluis/CrossSimpleAudioPlayerSample

Comment: I upvoted, because I heard the sound on simulator, however I am not hearing anything on a real device. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you're saying Simulator I'm assuming iOS? Did you flip the silent mode switch?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did. I also turned the volume to max and I tried manually to set the audio.Volume = 1.00; This happens with iPhone 6s with 12.4.1 iOS.

Comment: Yeah, OK. Set the audio manually in code you mean? But did you flip the actual physical silent mode switch on the side of the device? :)

Comment: Yeah, of course I did. This is the first thing one can think of :)

Comment: I have no idea why, but after few days, without any code change the sound appeared. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ha! Maybe some kind of old code that was cached somewhere? Anyway, glad it worked out!